# In Python, why attribute is not found even if it's listed in dir(object)?

Tags: python

i am using regionprops() from skimage.measure (version 0.19.3). It returns a list of RegionProperties objects. I can access all the various attributes from these RegionProperties (like area, major_axis_length, eccentricity...). But when i try to access the attributes related to intensity (intensity_mean, intensity_min, intensity_max) it returns this error:

```
AttributeError: '<class 'skimage.measure._regionprops.RegionProperties'>' object has no attribute 'intensity_mean'
```

When i print dir(region_property), where region_property is an instance of the class, it shows that intensity_mean/min/max are, in fact, between the object's attributes:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_cache', '_cache_active', '_extra_properties', '_image_intensity_double', '_intensity_image', '_label_image', '_multichannel', '_ndim', '_slice', '_spatial_axes', 'area', 'area_bbox', 'area_convex', 'area_filled', 'axis_major_length', 'axis_minor_length', 'bbox', 'centroid', 'centroid_local', 'centroid_weighted', 'centroid_weighted_local', 'coords', 'eccentricity', 'equivalent_diameter_area', 'euler_number', 'extent', 'feret_diameter_max', 'image', 'image_convex', 'image_filled', 'image_intensity', 'inertia_tensor', 'inertia_tensor_eigvals', 'intensity_max', 'intensity_mean', 'intensity_min', 'label', 'moments', 'moments_central', 'moments_hu', 'moments_normalized', 'moments_weighted', 'moments_weighted_central', 'moments_weighted_hu', 'moments_weighted_normalized', 'orientation', 'perimeter', 'perimeter_crofton', 'slice', 'solidity']
```

How is this possible?

Here a minimal reproducible example of my code:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import string
import cv2
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops, regionprops_table

test_mask_img = cv2.imread(test_mask, 0)
label_img = label(test_mask)
if len(np.unique(label_img)) > 1:
    regions = regionprops(label_img)
    print(dir(regions[0]))
    print(regions[0].intensity_mean) # this returns the error
```

complete stacktrace:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent 
call last)
Cell In [44], line 13
 11 regions = regionprops(label_img)
 12 print(dir(regions[0]))
 ---> 13 print(regions[0].intensity_mean)
 14 # update area stats
 15 update_stats(stats_dict=area_stats, 
 16             regions=regions, 
 17             c=c, 
 18             feature="area")

 File ~/ambiente/lib/python3.8/site- 
 packages/skimage/measure/_regionprops.py:352, in 
 RegionProperties.__getattr__(self, attr)
 350     return getattr(self, PROPS[attr])
 351 else:
 --> 352     raise AttributeError(
 353         f"'{type(self)}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
 354     )

 AttributeError: '<class 
 'skimage.measure._regionprops.RegionProperties'>' object has no 
 attribute 'intensity_mean'
```

Comment: I would guess that the object that you are calling `dir` on is not the same type of object as the object that you are trying to use `intensity_mean` on. You might think that they are, but I suspect that you are mistaken. Without a [mcve] I can do no more than guess.

Comment: Please, post [mre].

Comment: And while you're at it, post the full error message, including the stack trace.

Comment: You passed `regions[0]`, not `regions`, to `dir`.

Comment: In the error message, the line `print(regions[0].intensity_mean)` is flagged but in the code that you posted you have `print(regions.intensity_mean)`. Which is it?

Comment: @JohnColeman i'm sorry, i reported the code wrongly. In my code it's regions[0].intensity_mean. Also, i want to clear that i'm able to retrieve all the other attributes correctly, so something weird is happening. I'll edit my post, thank you

Comment: if you can use dir you should also be able to use vars and check if it is somehow special or missing in vars. As the traceback displays a custom attribute getter function this might be intended and I would recommend checking up with the documentations.

Comment: Since `test_mask` is undefined your code is not reproducible.

Comment: SOLUTION: I'm sorry for the bad formulation of the question. For everyone wondering, the solution is: you have to also pass the original image to the regionprops() function if you want to also use the intensity related attributes. It's obvious but the error is pretty silent. They solved it in one of  the last versions of sci-kit-image (see the github repo).